# Are there Right-to-Left versions of unicode characters for period, exclamation mark and colon?

Tags: unicode, utf-8

Are there a right-to-left versions of common symmetric punctuation marks such as `period «.»`, `exclamation mark «!»`, `colon «:»`? Note that since these characters are visually symmetric, a left-to-right version should be visually the same.

For asymmetric punctuation marks like `semicolon «;»` there is `«؛»`, for `comma «,»`, there is `«،»` and for `question mark «?»` there is `«؟»`.

**Motivation**: when writing texts with right-to-left characters, the visual positions of `period`, `exclamation mark` and `colon` occurring in the text change is some text editors. If there would be a right-to-left versions of these characters, this problem cannot arise.

Comment: Why do you need them? As you said yourself they are visually the same.

Comment: No, the characters you show are not general RTL versions of regular question mark etc, they are distinct Arabic characters

Comment: @user202729 I have added an explanation.

Comment: You need to apply the bidi algorithm properly, it accounts for all your RTL needs.

Comment: @n.m. try to insert `ا.` in a primitive text editor (or even here as a comment!). The correct position of `.` should be at the left of   `ا`, but it is not. If there would be a RTL version of `.:!` even in raw texts the positions were correct.

Comment: If you are writing a text editor and have a problem implementing RTL text, ask a question and I may be able to answer. If you are using a text editor and want to enter RTL text, then use a less primitive editor. Primitive ones are known to have incomplete implementatiins of Unicode BIDI algorithm. Unicode doesn't try to provide workarounds for broken software.

Comment: Specifically if you are typing a comment in a browser, you can press a key combination (right Ctrl+right Shift in chrome, Shift+Ctrl+X in Firefox) and switch the input field to RTL. then your punctuation in the end will look right. If you are writing a comment on SO it won't help the *posted* comment look right though. You will need to add HTML markup or BIDI override  characters for that.

Answer (score 1):

> Are there a right-to-left versions of common symmetric punctuation marks such as period «.»,  exclamation mark «!», colon «:»? Note that since these characters are visually symmetric, a left-to-right version should be visually the same.

As best as I'm aware, the answer to your question is no.

> Motivation: when writing texts with right-to-left characters, the visual positions of period, exclamation mark and colon occurring in the text change is some text editors. If there would be a right-to-left versions of these characters, this problem cannot arise.

To solve this, try entering a [right-to-left mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Right-to-left_mark) (RLM).

- If the punctuation is after the right-to-left text, enter the RLM after the punctuation. For example:

  - Without an RLM:
    أَنا اِسمي ...
  - With an RLM after the "...":
    أَنا اِسمي ...‏
- If the punctuation is before the right-to-left text, enter the RLM before the punctuation. For example:

  - Without an RLM:
    ...ـي
  - With an RLM before the "...":
    ‏...ـي
- If the punctuation is surrounded by right-to-left text, you shouldn't need an RLM.

How to enter the RLM will vary depending on your operating system (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_input#Hexadecimal_code_input):

- Linux

  1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>
  2. Type 200f
  3. Press <kbd>Space</kbd>
- Mac

  1. Press and hold down <kbd>⌥</kbd>
  2. Type 200f
  3. Release <kbd>⌥</kbd>
- Windows

  1. Press and hold down <kbd>Alt</kbd>
  2. Press + on the *numeric keypad*
  3. Type 200f
  4. Release <kbd>Alt</kbd>